# What am I missing? [apache config]

Tags: apache, config

A month ago I purchased a domain & hosting. Besides dabbling in some HTML for fun a few years ago, I didn't have any experience in all this "technical stuff". After a month of "doing my homework", I'm still trying to figure out a few things and I haven't had much luck searching SO or Google...

I've really only been using Filezilla & Notepad up til this point - I've been trying to keep it simple. Browsing my server, I couldn't seem to find the file "httpd.conf" or "php.ini" (among other files & dirs). I've been dabbling in .htaccess as an alternative but I've hit a roadblock since not all configs go in .htaccess files.

I made a phpinfo() script. Within that info, it shows "/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini" - yet this directory isn't shown in filezilla.

I know I must be missing something - how do I back up, access this directory & edit those configuration files?

Thank you so much for your help & deepest apologies if I've made you facepalm :P

-adraedin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just purchase hosting (as opposed to a virtual server), you will not usually have access to system-wide configuration files like `php.ini` or the global `httpd` configuration directories.
Instead, you can perform a limited subset of configuration through [`.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) in your directories.

The reason you don't see the configuration directories is that your FTP access only shows you your own directory, neither those of other users on your server, nor the system-wide configuration or other software that might be running there.

Comment: (not enough rep to +1 this answer) Sufficient answer. Okay, now for a bit more clarity - am I the server admin or is that my hosting company? I read about "sudo commands" ~ Unix/Linux ..... Is that stuff in their hands?

Comment: @adraedin: glad to be helpful. Your hosting company has the admins. As far as they're concerned, they give you a directory, FTP (most likely) access to it, and automated wiring to make that directory visible on the web. From what you say, you probably can't log into "the server" at all to issue commands, let alone sudo commands.

Comment: :D Follow up question for you: Considering NOT being able to edit "php.ini" & "httpd.conf" - Can most of what I need done (albeit you don't know what I intend to do...) be done with the .htaccess file(s)? (ex. through modules and directives)

Comment: @adraedin: as you say, I don't know. I'm assuming your hosting package includes PHP and a MySQL database, so you can do pretty much whatever you want in terms on content generation. `.htaccess` files are more commonly used for things like redirecting or rewriting URLs on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini file is extremely important. It is highly unrecommended to edit this file unless you know what you're doing. The most likely reason you can't see it is because it is outside of your "privilege zone" (meaning its hidden by your hosting company). This is typically done so that you don't mess with other accounts and domains using the same server.

If you need a change something within the httpd.config or php.ini file, and you can't make the change in your .htaccess, usually you can contact your hosting company and they'll modify the file for you. It really just depends on what you're looking to change/modify/edit.

Most of the time, in regards to your hosting, you can only see your account/domain files. This keeps you restricted to a particular section of the hard drive so you don't start messing with other peoples files/configurations.

Comment: Equally as sufficient answer. Thanks!